# Google Invoice API, documentation?

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client

There is an API listed in Google APIs (oAuth2) that can be enabled with the service name invoice.googleapis.com. As per the description, it supposedly allows you to fetch Billing invoices for products like Google Adwords, Enterprise etc.

However, there does not seem to be any documentation available online. The PHP client (the one I'm using) also doesn't have an implementation for this.

Does anyone have any more information about this? Is this still in development?